# Which HTML5 attributes can be a URL?

Tags: html

Obviously `a href` and `img src`. Are there any others? How would you search for this?

Answer (score 1):

One of them is certainly srcset on the picture element, well its contains a URL but is maybe one.

Not sure how to properly search for one, maybe browsers have implemented some logic like that?
Mh, at least servo has implemented a generic get_url_attribute function which tries to converts any attribute to a URL https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/master/components/script/dom/element.rs#L997 sorry no help here

Comment: The `get_url_attribute` Daniel was referring to: https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/5a0be12e43f92fc64b1d8f5d35f9dadaa4b53521/components/script/dom/element.rs#L997